# Ajax , PHP mysql Database query - Network routing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have a question regarding retrieving data via ajax and php mysql.

Scenario 1:

Site is a no refresh web application where content is retrieved by ajax requests since we cannot perform a php query in site. (located in country A)

User is in (country B), he clicks visits a page that needs some data from our mysql database. We send an ajax request to a php file which in turn performs the query and sends back the response to the browser that can be used then to display the data with javascript.

Scenario 1 question:
How does the flow go in scenario 1?

I was thinking:

User web browser(country B) AJAX REQUEST ---> php file (country A) ---> back to user (country B)

Is this correct?

If so then this can be slow when user could be on the other side of the world from the webserver.

Comment: Where is your code??

Comment: It's not a question with code. It's theory regarding how requests are handled so I can decide whether I want to focus on a no refresh web site or use go with standard php written site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Ajax call is the same as opening a web site in your browser. The only difference is, that it is done in the background and can support more HTTP methods. So, if your website and your Ajax-call back-end relies in country A, the user in country B always makes a call to country A, no matter if it is Ajax or a regular call.

However, the described effect of yours, that it might be slower, because the call transfers over a large distance is irrelevant for your website. There are very, very fast wires accross the continents, which transfer the signals in approx. 2/3 of the speed of light (300'000km/s).

You should however be aware of the speed of the server in country A and its uplink to the ISP (is the connection of the data center to the ISP fast enough?)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Backend(PHP) and Frontend(AJAX) is located on the same server. DB however is located on the different server. It is totally upto you how you want to decide the flow considering the trade-offs in each scenario.

If backend and frontend are on different server then you'll have to take care of CORS(Cross origin) request by the server.

There will be very insignificant delay since data centers have very high uplink and downlink speed.
The effect will however be noticeable if you are transferring large amount of data.

Comment: So what your saying is as long as the front end and backend is located on the server, the ajax requests performs on the server itself? Not via the user's browser. Because I'd think that ajaxing a php file would be slow compared to a directly querying the mysql database.

Comment: No ajax request will not be performed on server. What I am saying is that the delay wont be very significant since data centers have high uplink. It will be sent to browser almost immediately.